# JSF Richfaces 4.5 unable to find resource JQuery.js

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I got project to work on glassfish 4.1, but it keeps coming up with `"unable to find resource JQuery.js"` on previous version of Richfaces and glassfish it worked a 100%. It now breaks my menus etc and have an annoying popup displaying the error.

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery.js"/>
```

or

```
<h:outputScript name="jquery.js" target="head"/>
```

does not work anymore, any suggestions?

Also made sure the core is incl.
POM:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0.CR1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.richfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>richfaces-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The dependencies incl:

```
sac-1.3
cssparser-0.9.14
guava-18.0
richfaces-4.5.0.CR1
richfaces-core-4.5.0.CR1
richfaces-a4j-4.5.0.CR1
```

Is there something missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
<h:outputScript library="org.richfaces" name="jquery.js"/>
```

What are you using this for? JQuery is automatically included with RichFaces.

Comment: Sometimes you just need jQuery on pages without rf components and don't want to include a different version than RF already provides to avoid conflicts.